# Do scratches on electric range burner elements affect its performance or function?

Tags: electric-stoves

My electric range is about 5 years old and over time the burner elements have become scratched- it looks like coating is being worn off- is that normal and does it affect the performance or function of the burner?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the burners have a coating on them? I haven't ever seen or heard of electric burners with coatings? Did they look like they had this coating when your stove was new?

Comment: [this](http://atmedia.imgix.net/9cebcedf251662c5458948164b30de42ce3bcaff?auto=compress&w=640.0&fit=max) shows what I'm talking about- is that not coating being worn off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for adding the photo, Ford, as I *think* I know what it is. Although your photo is nicely focused, it's not the real thing so I can't be 100% sure. It looks to be the built up bits of grease and other residues from the bottom of your cooking pans that have accumulated over the 5 years. Not saying you slopped lots but the smallest amounts of spatter from cooking will add up. I moved 6 months ago into a place with a new stove and I've done my best not to spill food and to always wipe up right away but I've noticed the burners getting marked. It doesn't wash off either. Do you find the elements you cook on the most are more marked?

But to answer your original question whether the scratches affect the burners' performance,  the answer is no. All they need to be able to do is heat up and even a knick in the metal wouldn't stop it from heating.

Answer (score 1):

Just asked an EE who states that yes it will affect performance, and over time the whole thing will just break down and stop working.  He did state that it should be fairly well protected so you should be alright electrically.

EDIT:  EE just looked at your photo and states that they should be fine, but to keep an eye on them.

Comment: Could you clarify what to look out for when keeping an eye on them, i.e. what kind of damage is not okay?

Comment: Do you understand how these elements are made?

Comment: Yes, I do, but I'm asking on behalf of the OP and future readers, so it'd be helpful if you added something useful to people in general.

Comment: Well, if between you and the qualified EE, you're able to clarify your answer (as I asked in my first comment), that'd be lovely. If you have further questions or concerns about moderators' role or powers... let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53132/discussion-between-jefromi-and-dougal-2-0-0). (or ask on [meta], of course) Those are great discussions to have, just not here. This space is purely for discussion of the answer, so I've removed meta comments.